# Uploaded FTP files do not reflect on website

Tags: image, file, web, ftp, updating

Uploaded files do not reflect on website.

I've done some editing offline and have uploaded the changes through FTP to my website. Some changes are shown but not on the navigation, logo, and header background (an image). I've copied every file exactly as it should go yet it doesn't reflect on the website.

The website is located on: http://www.vargasjpr.com

Any help on this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit:

The logo is supposed to show the logo of the company, not the "Inspiration" logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your browser hold down your SHIFT button and then with your mouse click REFRESH button near the url.  I suspect you are viewing the cached copy of old images and just need to clear your cache.

The other way is Tools -> Internet Options ... via browser menus.

---

This is the logo URL I see:  http://www.vargasjpr.com/images/logo.png

Another thing you can do if caching bad, is change the name of the logo file and in your code to logo2.png but clearing your cache should work.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike. Seeing as I could see some changes I didn't think that the browser cache was a problem. But the SHIFT+REFRESH trick did it beautifully. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Good luck with your project and thanks for the vote.

Comment: thank you helped me too. and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/17464/difference-between-ctrlrefresh-and-ctrlshiftrefresh) shows the difference between Ctrl+Refresh and Ctrl+Shift+Refresh, hope helps someone.